# Legend placement explanation

Tags: plotting, legending

Could anybody explain, how the coordinates in `Placed` influence each other?

```
ArrayPlot[RandomInteger[10, {400, 400}], 
ColorFunction -> "ThermometerColors", 
PlotLegends -> {Placed[
BarLegend[{"ThermometerColors", {0, 100}}, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, FontSize -> 12], 
 LegendLabel -> "D33 content in wt%", 
 LegendMarkerSize -> 300], {{.35, -.65}, {-0, -3.}}], 
 Placed[Graphics[{Thickness[0.05], Line[{{0, 25}, {10, 25}}], 
  Text[Style["200 nm", Black, FontSize -> 12], {10/2, 26}]}], {{0,
   0}, {-1, 3.}}]}]
```

Which gives:
[image: Misplaced Legends]

EDIT:
I would like to have the black bar on the left hand side and the legend on the right hand side, below the arrayplot. I the alignment should be horizontally, not vertically.

Answer (score 6):

Placement in Placed is `{{x_pos, y_pos}, {x_obj_pos, y_obj_pos}}`, where `x_pos` and `y_pos` are scaled(from 0 to 1) position referring to the plot, and `x_obj_pos` and `y_obj_pos` are scaled position referring to the legend object. Scaled values can be outside the range of `{0,1}`.

```
ArrayPlot[RandomInteger[10, {400, 400}], 
 ColorFunction -> "ThermometerColors", 
 PlotLegends -> {Placed[
    BarLegend[{"ThermometerColors", {0, 100}}, 
     LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, FontSize -> 12], 
     LegendLabel -> "D33 content in wt%", LegendMarkerSize -> 300, 
     LegendLayout -> "Row"], {{1, 0}, {1, 1}}], 
   Placed[Graphics[{Thickness[0.05], Line[{{0, 25}, {10, 25}}], 
      Text[Style["200 nm", Black, FontSize -> 12], {10/2, 26}]}], {{0,
       0}, {0, 1}}]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
bl1 = Graphics[{Thickness[0.05], Line[{{0, 25}, {10, 25}}],
    Text[Style["200 nm", Black, FontSize -> 12], {10/2, 26}]}];
bl2 = BarLegend[{"ThermometerColors", {0, 100}},
   LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, FontSize -> 12],
   LegendLabel -> "D33 content in wt%",
   LegendMarkerSize -> 300, LegendLayout -> "Row"];
lgnd = Column[{bl1, bl2}, Alignment -> Center]
```

[image]

```
ap = ArrayPlot[RandomInteger[10, {400, 400}], ColorFunction -> "ThermometerColors"];

Legended[ap, Placed[lgnd, Below]]
Labeled[ap, lgnd, Bottom]
Panel[ap, lgnd, Bottom, Appearance -> "Frameless"]
ArrayPlot[RandomInteger[10, {400, 400}], ColorFunction -> "ThermometerColors",
          PlotLegends -> Placed[lgnd, Below]]
```

all give

[image]

Or, to place the legends horizontally,

```
lgnd2 = Row[{bl1, bl2}, Alignment -> Center]
```

[image]

Change `lgnd` to `lgnd2` in the expressions above, e.g.,

```
Labeled[ap, lgnd2, Bottom]
```

to get

[image]